# how to set leaflet map to max height possible

Tags: html, css, leaflet

I have the following set up to place a leaflet map inside a known bootstrap dashoard (sb-admin2).

To do this i placed the map inside the container-fluid that sets the content of the page.

For now, the map only works with fixed height sizes. If i change the height or width of the view port the map vanishes.

Is there any way of setting up the map in the same place but with the full height available? (without scroll).

```
<div id="content-wrapper" style="max-height:100%;" class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div id="content">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-white topbar mb-4 static-top shadow">
    <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="mb-2">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" id="trucks_toogle_button">
            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
         </a>
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle icon_drone" id="drones_toogle_button">
            <img class="button_image" src="icon/drone_white.svg">
         </a>
         </div>
         <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:78%"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="sticky-footer bg-white" style="padding: 1em 0 1em 0;">
    </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome and sometimes when expanding or contracting the viewport size, odd stuff happens

Try using vh for height instead of %. vh means % of viewport height. Likewise vw is % of viewport width